# SDL2 SDL_SetEventFilter vs SDL_WaitEvent

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

I had a typical SDL event loop calling `SDL_WaitEvent`, and ran into a much-discussed issue (see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/sdl/comments/55ezaz/continuous_resize_event/) and [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23633/sdl-and-opengl-resize-window-event-question)) where my application was not able to re-draw during a resize because `SDL_WaitEvent` doesn't return until a resize is finished on certain platforms (Win32 & Mac OS). In each of these discussions, the technique of using `SDL_SetEventFilter` to get around it is mentioned and more or less accepted as a solution and a hack.

Using the `SDL_SetEventFilter` approach works perfectly, but now I'm looking at my code and I've practically moved all the code from my `SDL_WaitEvent` into my EventFilter and just handling events there.

Architecturally it's fishy as heck.

Are there any gotcha's with this approach of dispatching messages to my application in the function set by `SDL_SetEventFilter`, besides the possibility of being called on a separate thread?

Bonus question: How is SDL handling this internally? From what I understand, this resize issue is rooted in the underlying platform. For example, Win32 will issue a WM_SIZING and then enter its own internal message pump until WM_SIZE is issued. What is triggering the SDL EventFilter to run?

Comment: What's against `SDL_PollEvent`? Instead of waiting indefinitely for events, just poll them each cycle if any.

Comment: That doesn't help. SDL_PollEvent behaves exactly like SDL_WaitEvent and will block until resize/move is completed

Comment: If it solved the issue, I wouldn't post it as a comment, right? It was just an off-topic suggestion.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you'd like me to respond.
I am not using SDL_PollEvent because I do not need a timeout. I'd be wasting cycles needlessly by polling instead of just waiting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question after more experimentation and sifting through the source.

The way SDL handles events is that when you call `SDL_WaitEvent`/`SDL_PeekEvent`/`SDL_PeepEvents`, it pumps win32 until there's no messages left. During that pump, it will process the win32 messages and turn them into SDL events, which it queues, to return after the pump completes.

The way win32 handles move/resize operations is to go into a message pump until moving/resizing completes. It's a regular message pump, so your WndProc is still invoked during this time. You'll get a `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE`, followed by many `WM_SIZING` or `WM_MOVING` messages, then finally a `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE`.

These two things together means that when you call any of the SDL event functions and win32 does a move/resize operation, you're stuck until dragging completes.

The way EventFilter gets around this is that it gets called as part of the WndProc itself. This means that you don't need to queue up messages and get them handed back to you at the end of SDL_Peek/Wait/Peep Event. You get them handed to you immediately as part of the pumping.

In my architecture, this fits perfectly. YMMV.